# Laravel how to get users by roles dynamically from api endpoint

Tags: php, laravel, api

How can I get the users based on which role they have in `laravel`? I have roles like for example "admin", "author", "editor" and I want to have a dynamic `api`-endpoint.

so in my `api.php` I have:

```
Route::get('users/{role}', "Api\UserController@role");
```

and my Controller looks like this:

```
public function show()
{
    $user_role = User::whereHas(
        'roles',
        function ($q) {
            $q->where('name', 'admin');
        }
    )->get();

    return $user_role;
}
```

This works fine so far, but I want the endpoint to be dynamic, like if want all my  editor users the endpoint should be `api/users/editors` etc. etc.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function show($role) //example: $role = 'admin'
{
    return User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) use ($role) {
        $q->where('name', $role);
    })->get();
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but I think he need to pass more than one role.

Comment: @mare96 There is no hint in the question that he wants multiple roles to be selectable at once.

Comment: Fixed your answer.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks alot :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your controller function should look like this:

```
public function show(Role $role)
{
    $users = $role->users;

    return $users;
}
```

And your Role Eloquent Model should have these methods:

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_role')
}

public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'name';
}
```

Comment: You would need a custom route binding in this case, because otherwise Laravel will attempt to resolve a `Role` based on the `id` given in the URL parameter `{role}`.

Comment: @Namoshek Yes, that's right, I forgot about that, I'm gonna edit it right away.